# Slicing a pandas column based on the position of a matching substring

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to slice a pandas column called PATH from a DataFrame called dframe such that I would get the ad1 container's filename with the extension in a new column called AD1position.

```
          PATH
0         \
1         \abc.ad1\xaxaxa
2         \defghij.ad1\wbcbcb
3         \tuvwxyz.ad1\ydeded
```

In other words, here's what I want to see:

```
          PATH                       AD1position
0         \
1         \abc.ad1\xaxaxa            abc.ad1
2         \defghij.ad1\wbcbcb        defghij.ad1
3         \tuvwxyz.ad1\ydeded        tuvwxyz.ad1
```

If I was to do this in Excel, I would write:

```
=if(iserror(search(".ad1",[PATH])),"",mid([PATH],2,search(".ad1",[PATH]) + 3))
```

In Python, I seem to be stuck. Here's what I wrote thus far:

```
dframe['AD1position'] = dframe['PATH'].apply(lambda x: x['PATH'].str[1:(x['PATH'].str.find('.ad1')) \
                                     + 3] if x['PATH'].str.find('.ad1') != -1 else "")
```

Doing this returns the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I suspect that the problem is caused by the function in the slicer, but I'd appreciate any help with figuring out how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function:

```
In [17]: df['AD1position'] = df.PATH.str.extract(r'.*?([^\\]*\.ad1)', expand=True)

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
                  PATH  AD1position
0                    \          NaN
1             \aaa\bbb          NaN
2             \byz.ad1      byz.ad1
3      \abc.ad1\xaxaxa      abc.ad1
4  \defghij.ad1\wbcbcb  defghij.ad1
5  \tuvwxyz.ad1\ydeded  tuvwxyz.ad1
```

Comment: This was the best answer. It answered my  I also updated my pandas to v. 18.1 so that I can use the expand argument. It looks like your function covers the possibility of a PATH being "\aaa\axy.ad1\bbbbb" but I'm not sure if it'll handle values like "\byz.ad1" (i.e., without the \ at the end) or "\def.ad1.ad1\ccccc" (i.e., repeating extensions in the filename), but I think that I should be good from here.

Comment: @Xavier, you are right - i've corrected my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the first element of the split.

```
df['AD1position'] = df.PATH.str.split('\\').str.get(1)
```

Thank you Root.

Comment: You can do `df.PATH.str.split('\\').str.get(1)`, but will the portion of the path containing `'.ad1'` always be element 1?  It is in the example data, but it's unclear to me from the question if this will always be the case.

Comment: I see no counter example present.  KISS method is needed.

Comment: How the heck does that work?  (doesn't the 2nd "str" turn the list into a string?)  shouldn't this return one letter?  Yes I tried it and it does work but ... HOW?

Comment: I don't know that it's documented anywhere but some of the `.str` methods will also work on lists (`len` and `get` come to mind).  The `.str` accessor doesn't turn anything into a string, I believe it's just there for code clarity, and to differentiate string functions from Series level functions when names might overlap, e.g. `df.PATH.replace()` vs. `df.PATH.str.replace()`.

Comment: The `get` functionality is documented [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings).  It also looks like using `.str[1]` would work in place of `.str.get(1)`.   I'm guessing that some of the `.str` methods happen to work on lists (or really any indexed object) because the underlying indexing is the same, i.e. you'd use `x[1]` to get the first element if `x` was a list, string, tuple, etc.

Comment: This was a clever solution, but I think that I saw some filenames with the .ad1 extension after element 1 on my original data (though I forgot to mention this in my original question), so I feel hesitant about this one.